# Unix/C++: Open new terminal and redirect output to it

Tags: c++, unix, redirect, terminal, stdout

My program (C++ on Solaris 10) writes output via wcout to its terminal when it is started from a shell. But when I execute it from within Sun Studio or the file manager is does not have a terminal and the ouput appears in the Sun Studio output window or nowhere at all.

I would like it to open its own terminal window in any of the three cases and attach wcout to this terminal window. I want this to be done be the program itself with C++ system calls not by the way how the program is executed from some shell or script. Because then execution in the Studio IDE and double-click in the file manager would still have the same effect.

Being a Windows programmer that seems quite natural to me but I could not find out how this is done in my Unix books nor in the web. Am I requesting the wrong thing, is it really so hard to do or am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I requesting the wrong thing?" - Sort of. Command-line tools generally don't create graphical entities like terminals. Generally, they rely upon some higher/previous entity to create it for them. That way, they work equally well in the SunStudio console, in xterm, in gnome-terminal, on a paper terminal, etc. I'm not familiar with Solaris file manager, but I bet it has a feature for running programs in their own terminal.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is relevant, but it is not a command-line tool. The program is a server that runs together with a couple of other servers to build the application. Later on, it will be started by some sophisticated remote starting mechanism and I want it to display status information in its terminal for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiy and celtschk. +1 for both. I accept the one that responds precisely me question. But I will also check whether the simple approach fits better into the Unix way of doing things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is close to what you want. It still has a few bugs:

- The xterm cannot be normally closed (it closes when the program terminates, though). I have no idea why this is so.
- Before the intended output, a number is output. Again, I have no idea why.
- I don't seem to be able to redirect input.

Maybe someone else know how to fix those bugs (and any others I might not have noticed).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  int pt = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
  if (pt == -1)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not open pseudo terminal.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  char* ptname = ptsname(pt);
  if (!ptname)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not get pseudo terminal device name.\n";
    close(pt);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (unlockpt(pt) == -1)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not get pseudo terminal device name.\n";
    close(pt);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "xterm -S" << (strrchr(ptname, '/')+1) << "/" << pt << " &";
  system(oss.str().c_str());

  int xterm_fd = open(ptname,O_RDWR);
  char c;
  do read(xterm_fd, &c, 1); while (c!='\n');

  if (dup2(pt, 1) <0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not redirect standard output.\n";
    close(pt);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (dup2(pt, 2) <0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not redirect standard error output.\n";
    close(pt);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::cout << "This should appear on the xterm." << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "So should this.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(1);

  close(pt);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to output to a file (redirect, using a logging API or close stdout/reopen it as a file). And then tail it with `tail -f` in a terminal of your choice.

This has added benefit of saving your log output for review even if the terminal crashes/is killed.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke your program, instead of running: `myprog 1 2 3 a b c`, run `xterm -e myprog 1 2 3 a b c`.

Comment: This is what my Google research brought to me. But like I said, I want to do it from the program not from the call.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommnend to create a shell script that runs the terminal to which you pass your program to execute, then you should call that script instead of your program from the file manager.

Your script.sh:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> xterm -e /path_to_your_program/your_program

Answer (score 0):

Using `mknod` to create pipe in /tmp every linux have /tmp and everyone always allowed to use it

```
system("mknod /tmp/printing_pipe pipe");
system("qterminal -e tail -f /tmp/printing_pipe");
```

write to the `/tmp/printing_pipe` to use it